# Autopep8 is not formatting python files.. errror reads- Skipping non python code:

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, autopep8

Out of no where autopep8 is not working in VSCode. Im pretty new to all this btw.

Every time I try to format a .py file with autopep8, I get a crazy notification saying that autopep8 is skipping non python code. Then it lists the .py files I am working on. People have been saying in other solutions to edit the .json file. Where is it? it doesnt seem to be listed in the manage settings
It worked perfect last week.....

I expect some type of formatting, indentations, recognize that I am currently attempting to format python code.

```py
letters = ["a", "b", "it"]

    letters.append("d")
    letters.insert(0, "-")
    letters.insert(3, "f")
     print(letters) #Why wont it remove this indention? How is this not considered python code?
```

Comment: Does `autopep8` handle whitespace that causes a syntax error?

Comment: No Python formatter is ever going to remove an indentation completely, as that would change the meaning of the code.  All they're going to do is ensure that indentations are to standard positions (perhaps 4 spaces per level).

Comment: That's an important point.  A Python formatter takes syntactically valid Python code and converts it to syntactically valid Python code that looks a bit different.  No formatter can fix syntax errors, which is what you have there.  That's just not its job.

Comment: It should still do somthing.... I cant get it to fix an incorrect indentation from 5 to 4, like a print statement within an if statement. Right?